# How do we test if synergy actually going?

Tags: ubuntu, synergy

Intended server: Windows XP

Intended client: Ubuntu Linux

- What happens - server/client is running.

Server debug:

```
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG1: no neighbor right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,814
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG2: find neighbor on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,611
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG2: ignored "LinuxPC" on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,640
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG2: no neighbor on right of "LinuxPC"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,626
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG1: try to leave "WINXP" on right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,808
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG1: no neighbor right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,814
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG2: find neighbor on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,611
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG2: ignored "LinuxPC" on right of "WINXP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,640
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG2: no neighbor on right of "LinuxPC"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,626
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG1: try to leave "WINXP" on right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,808
2011-04-12T01:40:06 DEBUG1: no neighbor right
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,814
2011-04-12T01:40:08 DEBUG1: event: button press button=1
    ..\lib\platform\CMSWindowsScreen.cpp,1273
2011-04-12T01:40:08 DEBUG1: onMouseDown id=1
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,1661
2011-04-12T01:40:09 DEBUG1: event: button release button=1
    ..\lib\platform\CMSWindowsScreen.cpp,1280
2011-04-12T01:40:09 DEBUG1: onMouseUp id=1
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,1671
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I test that port 24800 (or whatever it is) is open or closed ? (I have ZoneAlarm).
2. How do I test if the server/client is "listening" on the correct IP addresses?

   (refer to my suggestion - more logging - http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy2/forums/forum/199580/topic/4442168)
3. How do I test if my IP addresses are actually running the Synergy program?

Comment: nestat -a is the command your looking for to see if the windows machine is listening on port 24800 (you should probably find out exactly which port needs to be open).

Answer (score 0):

telnet to the port to see if it's open. You will get a Synergy+ message.

the command is:

```
telnet hostname 24800
```

This works on both Linux and Windows if you have Windows' telnet client installed.

Comment: my synergy IS using port 24800.  Is there a way to tell if the client can "see" the server (or other way round ?)

Comment: If you can ping each computer from the other, they can see each other. If you run "telnet servername 24800" from the client and it pops up with a prompt saying "Conected to... Synergy" or something similar, it means the client can connect to the server on port 24800 and that port is running Synergy.